# How to perform animated transitions of a view inside a ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `ScrollView`, which contains an `HStack`, which contains a `ForEach`, which contains some custom view with an attached transition. It looks something like:

```swift
ScrollView {
    HStack {
        ForEach(self.objects) { object in
            ObjectView(object)
                .transition(.slide)
        }
    }
}
```

When I update the contents of `self.objects` (within a call to `withAnimation`), I want the old/new `ObjectView`s to animate in and out as specified by the transition.

Unfortunately, no animated transitions appear. If I remove the `ScrollView` (leaving the `HStack` to be the root view), the animated transitions work as expected.

Is there a way I can animate the transitions of views inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: Every time I find an explicit animation that does not work, I try an implicit animation instead. Not a solution, but may help in debugging. I have not seen your code, but one of the reasons I found withAnimation to not work, is that if the binding updated inside the closure, in turn makes the BindableObject to call didChange.send() inside a DispatchQueue.main.async {}, the animation will not work. Which makes sense, according to the comments in the withAnimation declaration file.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are interested...this works:

```
struct ObjectView : View {

    var text: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var objects = ["a", "b", "c"]

    var body: some View {

        Group() {
            Button("add") {
                withAnimation() {
                    self.objects.append("f")
                }
            }
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(objects, id: \.self) { object in
                        ObjectView(text: object)
                            .transition(.slide)
                    }
                }.frame(width: 500)
            }
        }
    }
}
```